# Using inheritance or templates for generic wrapper class

Tags: c++, generics, polymorphism

Right now, I'm trying to abstract away the differences between a matrix and a scalar in C++ in terms of construction and operations. For the reference, the LA lib is Eigen.

I want something like this to work:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo{
    Foo(T _val) : val(_val) { ... };
    ... // implementation
    T val;
}

operator+(Foo lhs, Foo rhs){
    ... // do something
}
```

So that when I do this:

```
Foo<MatrixXd> lhs(MatrixXd(2,2));

// implicitly calls Foo(10), becomes Foo<int>, 
// and does elementwise addition for example
lhs + 10;
```

Now this is all good and dandy, but everyone knows that template is just duck typing, so these objects are actually different, and you can't stuff them into a generic container like:

```
vector<Foo> v; // obviously doesn't work; needs to have a typename specified
v.emplace_back(MatrixXd(2,2)); // and obvs these won't work either.
v.emplace_back(10);
```

So I thought about doing it polymorphically using inheritance, like:

```
class Foo{
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Base> _val) { val = std::move(_val); };
    Foo(int _val) { val = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(_val)); };
    ... // implementation
    std::unique_ptr<Base> val;
}

operator+(Foo lhs, Foo rhs){
    auto ans = lhs.val + rhs.val; // something like this
    ...
}
```

But this approach suffers from the ugly-syntax-problem:

```
Foo lhs(new MatrixXdWrapper(3));
lhs + 2; // 2 gets implicitly copy constructed on the heap
```

And I'd have to specify one for every single type, which is ugly and undesirable.

So my question is: *Are there workarounds for the issue of either of these approaches? Or is there a third approach I'm missing (perhaps a hybrid of the two) that people usually use for these generic container types that can interact with each other?*

Thanks!

Comment: Mold the two. [Type erasure](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure).

Comment: @StoryTeller Still going over the link at this moment, but it seems like it's the perfect solution for this problem :) thanks!

Comment: Glad it makes sense :) You should check out [Sean Parent's lecture](http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations#title-better-code-runtime-polymorphism). It touches and expands upon the subject more than the article I linked.

Comment: `std::any` can be used for "stuffing" the types into the container. refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808060/6459731.

Comment: @WARhead it's quite difficult to coerce into c++17, if I want general portability. However, I do see a solution using the polymorphic pImpl idiom, which I assume is roughly how `std::any` is done. I also suppose there is an equivalent in `boost::any`.

Comment: But probably [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/40807774/6459731) question's answer will hold the answer to this question. the question is also for using multiple types for a container

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a matrix to a number? (I am asking you in math, of course). As far as I know that operation is not define. I think your problem is with your design, not with your implementation. Nobody is going to understand your code, because you can't add a matrix and a number.

If you want to "add" a matrix and a number you can do something like:

```
Matrix<10,10> A;
Matrix<10,10>::All_ones I;
int c;
auto res = A + c*I;
```

Everyone who knows linear algebra can understand that, and is very esay to implement.

I don't know if this is really what you want to do.

You also can overload the operator+:

```
 Matrix& operator+(Matrix& m, int c){
     // for all i, j:
     m(i,j) += c;
     return m;
 }
```

and that's all. I can't write the correct signature of the function because I don't know how is your Matrix define. Maybe you have to write something like:

```
template <size_t m, size_t n>
Matrix<m,n>& operator+(Matix<m,n>& m, int c)
{
  ...
 }
```

or something like that.

Of course, remember to define also "c + A", and if you want that your operator works also with differents types of ints (unsigned, long) or with double, you have or parameterized the operator with the type, or overload the operator+ for int, double...

Comment: "and does elementwise addition for example". It is generally well understood that `A+c` is an elementwise-addition of c onto the matrix A, such that (A + c)_{ij} = A_ij + c.

Comment: That is "A + c*I". You first, multiply c for the identity matrix, and then add A to the result. Sorry, "I" is not the identity matrix, is the matrix with all ones (my mistake). "I" is the matrix: I_{ij} = 1.

Comment: If you want to do add  a matrix to a number you can overload the operator+. I edit my answer again

Comment: Sorry, but that wasn't the purpose of the question. I understand how to overload these methods, but I do not know a very clean way of presenting a unified interface for multiple implementations of `Foo` depending on the inner type.